# Image Formula Field

Tags: formula-field, image-formula

I am trying to create an image field (Opp) to show one money dollar image if the closed mrc field is between 0 to 100, two money dollar images if its between than $200-299, three money dollar images if its $300-399, and one money BAG if its greater than $399. Problem is I have a gap in my formula it is not covering 101 -201 and I feel like this isnt written properly, Can anyone please advise?

```
IF( RecordTypeId = "012j0000000zPMn", 
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 101, 
IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq ", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 201, 
IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq ", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq ", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c <= 399,
IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq ", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq ", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq ", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c  >=  400, 
IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klk ", "Bag of Money", 30, 30),"")
))), "")
```

Comment: What are you suppose to show between 101 and 200?

Comment: the ranges need to be adjusted in the formula--- 0-199=one dollar image 200-299 two dollar images 300-399 three dollar images and 400+ money bag

Comment: Do not hard-code those URLs like that. This will break everytime you deploy between environments or if your org is migrated to another instance. You can use  "servlet/yourfile"

Comment: For example should i use servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq instead of https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start you can change the numbers in the if statement to get the right images to appear like so:

```
IF( RecordTypeId = "012j0000000zPMn", 
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 200, 
IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 300, 
IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 400,
IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klq", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c  >  400, 
IMAGE("https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klk", "Bag of Money", 30, 30),"")
))), "")
```

You should also not use the url https://c.na16.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j00000016Klk

Instead you should upload your files to [static resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources.htm).

The example below would be if you create two static resources named money and bag_of_money:

```
IF( RecordTypeId = "012j0000000zPMn", 
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 200, 
IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 300, 
IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 400,
IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c  >  400, 
IMAGE("/resource/bag_of_money", "Bag of Money", 30, 30),"")
))), "")
```

Additionally, I would use `RecordType.Name` instead of `RecordTypeId` as ids are different between all sandboxes and production

```
IF( RecordType.Name = "My Record Type Name", 
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 200, 
IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 300, 
IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c < 400,
IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30) & " " & IMAGE("/resource/money", "One Dollar", 30, 30),
IF( Closed_MRC__c  >  400, 
IMAGE("/resource/bag_of_money", "Bag of Money", 30, 30),"")
))), "")
```

Comment: My images are located in the documents tab under Grpahics Pack for Formulas already. Do I need to change this to do the static resource? Well seems like I have done this, how would I have the names of the resources to be the Money and Bag of Money

Comment: The issue will arise when you start using these images in other sandboxes or if your server changes from na16 to something else. Static resources are a safer bet because they can easily be moved when creating sandboxes or deploying to production and the urls won't change.  Right now, you would have to reupload those files in the new environment and change all your formulas to use the new ids for the documents.  It's a warning as it might become a headache in the future :)

Comment: Also, you could use RecordType Name instead of RecordType Id's so that it would work on production org as well. Because the Id's will be different in Production environment (except its in Full Sandbox)